# Identifying parallel and series capacitors for capacitor system with dieletric inserted

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, polarization, dielectric

> [image]
> [image]
>
> (Source:- JEE 2000).

What I did was prove that the electric fields in K1 and K2 are having the same E fields inside them(as shown in the image ). I then concluded that since the fields are uniform, constant and the distance which the dielectrics k1 and k2 occupies are the same, the potential drop across them should be the same. [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/558173/why-is-the-general-definition-of-electric-fields-in-dielectrics-breaking-down-he)

[image]

$$ \oint \vec{E} \cdot dl = 0$$

$$ \implies \vec{E_1} = \vec{E_2}$$

I hence concluded that Slabs k1 and k2 are in parallel and their equivalent would be in series with slab k3 and got the following answer (which is incorrect acc. soltn key).

$$k_{eff} = \frac{2(k_1 +k_2)k_3}{2k_3 + k_1 + k_2}$$

The correct answer given  is obtained when we take the slabs k1 and k2 each to be in series with half of k3 each and then taken in parallel.

$$C_{eq} = \frac{\epsilon_oA}{d} ( \frac{k_1k_3}{k_1 +k_3} + \frac{k_2 k_3}{k_2 + k_3})$$

**Concerns:-**

1. If the voltage differences across the slabs k1 and k2 are equal why are they in series with k3 and not in parallel with each other?
2. On top of this, the capacitors in series have the same charges on them which doesn't seem to be the case here as $Q_{ind}$= $Q(1-\frac{1}{k})$ and since k is different, the charges on all the slabs are different. One of my friends responded to this by stating that capacitors in series need not always have the same charge and gave an example of two capacitors connected by an inductor.

Comment: Who says the voltage across the slabs is equal? Also, this post is hard to read with all the handwritten calculations. If you're going to include them, you should use MathJax, but I don't actually think they're relevant at all to the question.

Comment: I proved them to be equal as E fields in both are the same and their distances are same then by V=Ed both have same potential difference

Comment: First of all, your "proof" assumes that the electric field in each dielectric is uniform, which I don't think is true in this example. But I was responding to your question "If the voltage differences across the slabs are equal why are they in series?" I thought you were asking about 1 and 3 or 2 and 3, since these are the ones in series. If you're asking about 1 and 2, the answer is: they're not in series.

Comment: I am saying is K1 in parallel with k2.Please refer to my diagrams

Comment: And why would the fields not be uniform ?

Comment: Also I edited the series concern

Comment: Can't you split the one capacitor into two parallel connected capacitors with half of the plate area each? Then, can't you split both of those capacitors into two series connected capacitors with one type of dielectric each?

Comment: [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6HAc.png)

Comment: But what's wrong with first taking them in parallel and then series

Comment: Like how I drew them in the image with option B at the bottom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Charge distribution on a plate of Capacitor with Dielectrics .](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29624/charge-distribution-on-a-plate-of-capacitor-with-dielectrics)

Comment: Not exactly.Firstly I have managed to prove that the fields are equal and that the potential drops across them are the same . Secondly, if they are in series they ought to have the same charges (as capacitors in series do ) which I can't see to be happening here.

Comment: This comes in the first results of google images if one searches parallel vs series capacitors.. good question but you need to have used latex.

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz , I think what would help is if you read the [atomic level phenomenon in a dielectric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric). You have applied the same **external electric field** across $k_1$ and $k_2$. But internally, the electric field decreases due to polarisation of dielectric. The internal electric field is inversely proportional to $k$. And this internal electric field is what you should consider when finding potential across the dielectric. Since $k_1$ and $k_2$ are different,  so is their internal electric field and so is the potential across them.

Answer (score 1):

> But what's wrong with first taking them in parallel and then series

Let the three capacitances in your proposed connection be $C_1$, $C_2$, and $2C_3$. The equivalent capacitance is then

$$C = 2\frac{(C_1 + C_2)C_3}{C_1 + C_2 + 2C_3} $$

Now, think about what happens when, say, $k_1$ is made much, much greater than $k_2$ and $k_3$. The equivalent capacitance would go to

$$C\rightarrow 2\frac{C_1C_3}{C_1} = 2C_3 = 2\frac{\epsilon_0k_3A}{d}$$

This doesn't pass the sanity check. It doesn't seem plausible that making $k_1$ arbitrarily large should negate the effect of the $k_2$ slab entirely.

The equivalent capacitance of the correct parallel combination of two series connected capacitors is

$$C = \frac{C_1C_3}{C_1 + C_3}+\frac{C_2C_3}{C_2 + C_3}$$

and the limit of arbitrarily large $k_1$ is

$$C\rightarrow C_3 + \frac{C_2C_3}{C_2 + C_3} \lt 2C_3$$

This *does* pass the sanity check. Only if $k_2$ is also made arbitrarily large does the equivalent capacitance approach $2C_3$.

So where has your thinking gone wrong? If the connection you propose is valid, then we can insert an ideal conductor plate at the interface of the $k_3$ dielectric with the others without changing the system. But I'm almost certain that's not the case.

With the plate there, the electric field lines must be 'vertical' (normal to the plate) at the interface. But, without the plate there, I don't believe that there's a requirement that the field lines are normal to the dielectric interfaces.

Comment: Umm but aren't the field lines already normal?I still dont quite follow how that causes a problem ? Does my proof of E1=E2 only hold for infintely large plates

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz, I just discovered that your question is essentially an exact duplicate of [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29624/9887). I think it would be good to try to merge the two together somehow.

Comment: But I proved that the middle interface is an equipotrntial when I proved that the fields in those dielctrics were the same?

Comment: Wait if they are in series how do they have same charges ?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz, two series connected capacitors have the same *voltage across* only if they have the same capacitance. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No. I am aksing if k1 and half of k3 are in series then they must have same charges on them .Here it doesn't seem so